# From where to start for URL rewrite in nginx?

Tags: apache, url-rewriting, nginx

I am new to nginx, and i would like to know from where I can start URL rewrite in nginx,

I know with apache we can have .htaccess file. but for whenever I have search for ngingx i just get the rules and syntax and all that. But i would like to know in which file I have to write these rules just like .htaccess file for apache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

nginx doesn't have an equivalent to .htaccess files, you need to put the rewrite rules in the server config.

Comment: you mean I need to write in conf file of the nginx?

Comment: Yes. BTW, the main place for rewrite rules in Apache, as with basically every webserver software, is in the conf file. htaccess files are just an additional convenience feature.